# Where are the meta-titles for categories set/created by default?

Tags: category, meta-tags

I want to change my page titles for categories but cannot find where it's originally set.

Right now, they look usually like this: Laptops - Computers - Electronics - Magento

But I cannot find the piece of code that lines up all the categories and seperates them with " - "

I expected it to be in

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
```

Or in

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View
```

Or maybe

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
```

but it was nowhere to be found.

In Category_View the title gets only set when there is a title set in the backend:

```
if ($title = $category->getMetaTitle()) {
      $headBlock->setTitle($title);
}
```

but there's no `else` after that.

In     `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` there is the method `getDefaultTitle()` which I'd expect to be called when no title has been set.

I am aware that I don't necessarily need to find that piece of code to change my title but it would certainly help to understand magento better.

For clarification: 
I am talking about meta-titles.
I know how to set them.
I want to know where they are set that they look like this:
Laptops - Computers - Electronics - Magento

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's located in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs`.

This isn't the most obvious location but kind of makes sense as the breadcrumbs are displayed in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is what you're looking for but in

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

OR

```
app/design/frontend/BASE/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

is where gets the title for frontend with this code

```
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i'm talking about meta-titles. changed in original post

Comment: Um, there's no `<meta title="" />`, only `<title />` in the `<head />` section. It's kind of embarrassing, all the people who ask about meta-title tags. Titles have always been a distinct part of the HTML page. Magento confuses the issue by having the Title in the meta tags section in Category and Product  Maintenance.

Comment: my mistake, sorry @user9855

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your theme or parent theme layout files you removed breadcrumbs block like this way

```
 <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
```

dynamic page title set from **Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs** so you must use this block in your site to make page titles dynamic. If you don’t want to show breadcrumbs just keep the phtml file **empty** (/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml)